# Does replacing axel cvs imply replacing the cv boots as well?

Tags: axle, cv-boot

I got an estimate for replacing my cv axels today and I was wondering if this job includes replacing the cv boots. I am not knowledge on this subject, so this may be a dumb question, but are cv boots likely to be included in my estimate?

Comment: Are you just having the CVJoints replace, or the entire half shaft?

Comment: I believe it is  the entire half shaft on both sides.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in almost all cases the replacement CV axle comes as a sealed unit.  It is pretty rare to hear of shops replacing individual joints (boots), when it is generally more cost effective to just replace the entire part.

Also, torn boots are typically the reason the axle is being replaced, so it wouldn't make sense to "re-use" them from your old axle.  Most CV axles fail because the rubber boots rip/tear.  Then the grease leaks out and dirt/road grime gets in places where it shouldn't be.